# Tell ipython to keep temp files

Tags: ipython

There have been a few occasions in which I've got some code in some temp files thanks to ipython's %edit feature, and through some tragic sequence of events or other I end up exiting the shell before saving the code permanently.

Is there any setting anywhere that makes the temporary files, how should I say this ... not so temporary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `%edit filename.py` to keep your edits even after quitting the shell. if you want to use temp files, you could try configuring your [editor](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magic.py#L2111) to automatically save them.

you could also hack the ipython source and prevent the shell from cleaning up temp files when exiting: just comment the [5 lines after "# Cleanup all tempfiles left around"](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2536). just an idea :)

Comment: Thanks. I went for editing the source to ask me whether to clean those files up or not. I feel dirty doing it, but it works.

I'm guessing then that their are no settings.

Comment: no, there are no settings - you can confirm this looking at the source. if you don't want to feel dirty about your hack, try polishing it and sending a patch to the ipython community to get it included into the distribution.

if this answer solved your question, consider marking it "accepted".

Comment: Thanks ax! I'll look into sending in a patch.